# Meu formulario dinamico em vue nao funciona

Tags: vue.js

Eu estou fazendo um formulário, no qual é necessário que eu permita adiconar mais campos. Eu já consegui fazer isso em outros campos desse mesmo formulario. 
No entanto, tudo que já tentei para um último campo dá errado.

A div que quero adicionar dinamicamente:

```
        <div class="field opcao" v-for="(op, x) in body.fields.options" :key="x">
            <label class="label">Opção de resposta para o campo anterior</label>
            <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Ex.: Couro" v-model="body.fields[index].options[x]">
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="button btn-secondary" @click="addOption(index)">Adicionar opção de resposta para o campo</button>
```

O JS:

```
addOption(){
            this.body.fields[index].options.push('');
        }
```

e meu JSON é assim:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu form inteiro está assim e para os outros campos está funcionando normalmente.

```
   <form class="central">
                    <div class="field subcategoria cartao" v-for="(t, index) in body.type" :key="index" >
                        <label class="label">Nome da Subcategoria {{index}} *</label>
                        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Ex.:Casaco" required v-model="body.type[index]">
                        <small>Os campos da subcategoria ajudarão a definir melhor as características do objeto, para que suas chances de ser encontrado sejam maiores.</small>
                        <div class="field central">
                            <form class="central central">
                                <div class="campo central">
                                    <div class="field">
                                        <label class="label">Nome do campo *</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Ex.: Material" required v-model="body.fields[index].name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="field opcao" v-for="(op, x) in body.fields.options" :key="x">
                                        <label class="label">Opção de resposta para o campo anterior</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Ex.: Couro" v-model="body.fields[index].options[x]">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="button btn-secondary" @click="addOption(index)">Adicionar opção de resposta para o campo</button>                  
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" class="button btn-secondary">Adicionar campo</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="button btn-secondary" @click="addNewSubcategorie()">Adicionar subcategoria</button>
                    <button type="button" @click="imprimir()">console</button>                      
                </form>
```

Comment: Acabei de descobrir pelo console, que ele está adicionando as posições ao vetor options. Mas o campo nao aparece na tela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A detecção de alterações em `Objects` e `Arrays` no Vue.js é limitada ao momento de criação da instância do componente. O Vue.js não consegue reconhecer adição ou remoção de novas propriedades em objetos, visto que o Javascript não possui uma ferramenta ou API que possibilite a customização destes comportamentos (veja na documentação do Vue.js as [limitações de `Objects`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Limitacoes-na-Deteccao-de-Alteracoes) e [limitações de `Arrays`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Limitacoes)).

Já que o Javascript não permite monitorar as adições/remoções de atributos a objetos nativamente, a saída é usar solicitar que o Vue.js faça as adições/remoções, dessa maneira o próprio framework cuidará de manter a reatividade do objeto para você.

Para solicitar que o Vue altere este objeto mantendo a reatividade, você deve usar as funções [`Vue.set()`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-set) para adicionar uma nova propriedade e [`Vue.delete()`](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/api/index.html#Vue-delete) para remover. Dessa maneira o Vue vai estar ciente das alterações que você fez no objeto.

#### Exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
        // Objeto exemplo
        propriedades: {
            prop_1: "Propriedade 1",
            prop_2: "Propriedade 2"
        },
        // Um contador simples só para criar as novas propriedades
        qtd_props: 2,
    }),
    methods: {
        add_prop_errado() {
            // Incrementa o contador
            this.qtd_props += 1
            // Prepara os dados (para o código a seguir ficar mais claro)
            let prop = "prop_" + this.qtd_props
            let valor = "Propriedade " + this.qtd_props
            
            // Operação que o Vue não consegue reconhecer
            this.propriedades[prop] = valor
        },
        add_prop_certo() {
            // Incrementa o contador
            this.qtd_props += 1
            // Prepara os dados (para o código a seguir ficar mais claro)
            let prop = "prop_" + this.qtd_props
            let valor = "Propriedade " + this.qtd_props
            
            // Encarrega o Vue de atribuir a nova propriedade
            Vue.set(this.propriedades, prop, valor)
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <button @click="add_prop_errado">Adicionar (errado)</button>
    <button @click="add_prop_certo">Adicionar (certo)</button>
    <ol>
        <li v-for="(valor, prop) in this.propriedades" :key="prop">
            <strong>{{ prop }}</strong>: {{ valor }}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

---

Vale lembrar que o mesmo pode ser utilizado para Arrays. Exemplo:

```
let array = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5]

// Maneira INCORRETA
array[2] = 3

// Maneira CORRETA
Vue.set(array, 2, 3)
// ou
this.$set(array, 2, 3)
```

---

#### Conclusão

Agora cabe a você analisar o seu código para descobrir onde você está criado ou removendo uma propriedade de maneira que o Vue não reconheça.

Uma opção também seria substituir o objeto inteiro, assim você estará modificando um atributo que já é reativo. Porém não é uma opção performática, você precisaria analisar o impacto de performance no seu projeto.

Exemplo:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
        propriedades: {
            prop_1: "Propriedade 1",
            prop_2: "Propriedade 2"
        },
        qtd_props: 2,
    }),
    methods: {
        add_prop() {
            this.qtd_props += 1
            let prop = "prop_" + this.qtd_props
            let valor = "Propriedade " + this.qtd_props
            // Cria um cópia de `propriedades`
            let novo_propriedades = {...this.propriedades}
            // Modifica a cópia
            novo_propriedades[prop] = valor
            
            // Substitui o objeto reativo inteiro pela cópia modificada
            this.propriedades = novo_propriedades
        },
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <button @click="add_prop">Adicionar</button>
    <ol>
        <li v-for="(valor, prop) in this.propriedades" :key="prop">
            <strong>{{ prop }}</strong>: {{ valor }}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```